# Как правильно писать запросы в Postgresql, если мы имее несколько ссылок(у которых одинаковый Id) из дочернего объекта на основной?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

Приведу примеры моделей

```
class News(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'news_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    head = Column(String)
    body = Column(String(350))
    date = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=sql.func.now())
    news = News.__table__

class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comments_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    body_c = Column(String)
    news = relationship("News", backref='comments')
    news_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('news_table.id', 
        ondelete="CASCADE"))

    comment = Comment.__table__
```

Мне необходимо получить все новости с их комментариями, при запросе вида:

```
SELECT * FROM comments_table INNER JOIN news_table 
ON news_table.id = comments_table.news_id;
```

Я получаю результат вида:

```
id |  head  |  body  |             date              | id | body_c | news_id 
----+--------+--------+-------------------------------+----+--------+---------
 1 | string | string | 2021-03-23 10:47:11.573694+07 |  1 | string |       1
 1 | string | string | 2021-03-23 10:47:11.573694+07 |  2 | funcq  |       1
(2 строки)
```

Хотя ожидаю только 1 новость и 2 комментария, а не вывод двух одинаковых объектов соответственно.
Понимаю, что проблема с запросом, но не понимаю куда копать. Если укажете на ошибки буду очень признателен.

Comment: Приведите пример того, что вы хотите получить. В данный момент без имён колонок в примере результата не очень ясно что и как

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в news атрибут `comments = relationship("Comment")`, это позволит после создания записи доставать комментарии по полю новостей. Вот так: `News.comments`.

Доставать новости можно через `sqlalchemy orm`, вот так:

```
>>> news = session.query(models.News).first()
>>> print(news.comments)
[<models.Comment object at 0x1062f6b20>, <models.Comment object at 0x1062f6c10>]
```

> Мне необходимо получить все новости с их комментариями, при запросе вида:SELECT * FROM comments_table INNER JOIN news_table  ON news_table.id = comments_table.news_id; Я получаю результат вида:

Ваш запрос вернёт 2 строки, тк вторая таблица содержит 2 записи, по другому не бывает.